# Magento: generating url for a backend action (with key)

Tags: php, url, magento

I am working on a demo Magento store (CE v1.7)

I want to generate a link for an action (index) of a controller (index) of the module (Mymodule), I want to display the link in the home page so I can access to Mymodule functionnality directly

how can I achieve this (without disabling the keys generation)?

I have already tried the following code, but I get redurected to the dashboard:

```
<?php $key = Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/url')->getSecretKey("acompany_mymodule/index/","index"); ?>
    <a href="<?php echo Mage::helper("adminhtml")->getUrl("acompany_mymodule/index/index/",array("key" => $key)); ?>">My action </a>
```

Answer (score 57, accepted):

A secret key should automatically be added to the URL when using

```
Mage::helper("adminhtml")->getUrl("acompany_mymodule/index/index")
```

provided that secret keys are enabled in the system config.

Anyway, in this part of your code :

```
<?php 
      $key = Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/url')
             ->getSecretKey("acompany_mymodule/index/","index"); 
 ?>
```

you give as first parameter a route with a controller, where the method is just waiting for a controller name.

DON'T USE anything else than `adminhtml/` as start of the url, because magento 1.9.2.2 forbids everything else.

Comment: Well done - does this also work in frontend? I need this, because I want to create an email with a link to the specific backend entity. Or is it required to use app emulation in this case?

Comment: FYI: Depending on the `config.xml` router settings of the module in question, you may need to prefix the string in`getUrl()` with `adminhtml/`. For instance, `Mage::helper("adminhtml")->getUrl('adminhtml/system_convert_profile/edit', array('id'=>10));`

Answer (score 13):

use following code for get url with secret code

```
Mage::helper("adminhtml")->getUrl("adminshipper/process/index");
```

Please refer to the following article: [Generating Backend-Admin URL With Key and Parameters in Magento](http://subeshpokhrel.github.io/blog/2010/03/24/generating-backend-admin-url-key-parameters-magento/).

DON'T USE anything else than `adminhtml/` as start of the url, because magento 1.9.2.2 forbids everything else.

Answer (score 10):

The other solutions did not work for me as they did not include the Admin Panel base URL (*admin* by default). I had to do it like this to get the correct URL:

```
Mage::helper('adminhtml')->getUrl('adminhtml/name_of_custom_extension/name_of_controller/');
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be `Mage::helper('adminhtml')->getUrl('adminhtml/controller_name/action_name');`?