# read custom admin url magento

Tags: php, magento

How do you get custom admin url? Issue is that when I change filter option on custom module it redirects to default admin url and therefore goes to the dashboard. There is a lot of info regarding redirecting to the dashboard but since it is redirecting to default admin url this is somehow different.

I tried:
`<?php echo $this->getUrl('*/*') ?>`
and `<?php echo Mage::helper('adminhtml')->getUrl('adminhtml/xcategory') ?>`

Comment: Seems like you are missing the `package_modulename` in `getUrl`. What is the name of your custom package and module ?

Comment: Adding it as in my second example doesn't change anything.

Comment: Your second example doesn't have a prefix for the package and module.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11450146/magento-generating-url-for-a-backend-action-with-key

Comment: I had faced this type of problem. In my case there is problem in grid I missed one method in my controller that is grid action.

Comment: Actually it is a problem in grid. Thanks for tip.